# Calculus books And some advice

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, reference-request

I am a calculus beginner. I want a book to start with.

I also want some advice before I start.

Comment: What do you already know? Have you seen some trigonometry? Are you familiar with polynomials - how to multiply/divide them?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan. Yes, I know trigonometry very well. I am also very familiar with polynomials. I have mastered both of them

Comment: @ShreeshaEinstien I'm a 15 year old from America. Let me know if you'd like to discuss math or physics sometime.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter. That would be great. I love physics more than mathematics though. How can we do it, through email or social networks(Google+ is my preference)?

Comment: @ShreeshaEinstien As do I. I wish there was a sort of inbox on here. I'll put my email in my mathse bio for the next day. Go check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what you know, I would recommend that you look at the following :

1. Apostol's "Calculus Vol 1"
2. Serge Lang's "A first course in Calculus"
3. Stewart's "Early Transcendentals" or his "Calculus"
4. Thomas and Finney's "Calculus and Analytic Geometry"

I have taught using 1 and 3; and have referred to the others. Apostol is my favourite, and is what I would recommend if you want to take up mathematics seriously in the future. Stewart and Thomas/Finney are more geared towards applications, and have a lot of problems which are well worth doing.

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to use  Khanacademy, I am 13 years old and I know calculus thanks to that website, That site is really good.

Comment: That helped a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are several categories.

Calculus for math students as in [Spivak](http://books.google.com/books/about/Calculus.html?id=7JKVu_9InRUC).

Calculus for engineering/science/math students as in [Stewart](http://books.google.com/books?id=jBD0yTh64wAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=stewart&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4VFJUvKrMcme2wXg5YCICA&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=stewart&f=false), and many other similar ones

Calculus for health/social science majors [Hoffman](http://books.google.com/books?id=x7G4AAAACAAJ&dq=tan+calculus+business+hoffman&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qVJJUp8bsq7aBb6NgdgK&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAA)

Calculus for business majors [Tan](http://books.google.com/books?id=FjPGwYGMFbwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=tan+calculus+business&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZVJJUqK7CqWS2QWCxoGIBg&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=tan%20calculus%20business&f=false)

They also divide by homework software they come with as in WebAssign, MyMathLab, WebWork, MathPortal etc. These usually need an instructor's key before you can use them.

The level of rigor depends on the university you will attend. So it is  possible that a pre-med major in one university has a tougher calculus class than the engineering calculus course in another university.

There are a large number of online resources (mostly geared towards engineering/science students):

[Notes 1](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/)

[Screen cast videos 1](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus), [2](http://www.math.lamar.edu/faculty/maesumi/mathexpo.pdf),[3](http://online.math.uh.edu/HoustonACT/videocalculus/)

[Regular videos 1, not active](http://press.princeton.edu/video/banner/),[2](http://www.math.ncsu.edu/calculus/web/MA141lectures.html)

[Notes with step-by-step solutions, not active](http://archives.math.utk.edu/visual.calculus/)

Stick to one platform and fasten your seat belt!

Comment: I want calculus for physics career

Comment: @ShreeshaEinstien Then go with the books for the engineering group.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna learn some single variable calculus, MIT has [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7K1sB05pE0A&list=PL590CCC2BC5AF3BC1) series of youtube lectures. You can find multivariable calculus lectures of MIT [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxCxlsl_YwY&list=PL4C4C8A7D06566F38). Have fun!